# What resources are there to teach Ukrainian refugees music theory?

Tags: theory

I have a Ukrainian student in one of my music classes.  We can get past most of the language barriers with Google Translate, but the translation for music theory is a little too complicated sometimes.  Are there any good resources for converting western (US) music theory to the equivalent music theory used in Ukraine?  Thank you!

Comment: What level are they? Is there any reason not to teach them the theory you know the best?

Comment: High school level.  They do not know any English and I'm trying to make it relatable in Ukrainian so I thought it was be easier for me to reach over her side of the fence rather than make her learn a new concept and a new language at the same time.  I'm not sure how theory is taught and quite frankly don't have a lot of spare time to learn it, so if there are resources that already existed I could make assignments from those instead of   trying to create them myself.  I'm not beyond doing that, I just don't have the time.

Comment: That's awesome! Note, the [topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) don't include resource requests of the "point me toward a book that ___" sort. But seems to me the most important question is: What _are_ the differences in how it's taught? I recommend editing the question to ask that. And I'm guessing the core content is the same, except that Ukrainian (like many languages) [uses solfege syllables](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/122281/what-letters-are-used-for-guitar-chords-in-ukraine) rather than letters to name pitches.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm sure there are Ukrainian music theory textbooks; you could simply try to get hold of one (but then *you'd* have to figure out what you were reading!).

Comment: Your reputation score is high enough for the chat rooms. I suggest posting this question there. You might also try the [Ukrainian Language SE](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/) or chat room.

Comment: Your objective is laudable, however, asking for resources on this site will render the question closed. Sorry. However, if the student has been brought up using fixed do solfege, you're both going to have to adapt - there's little common ground from that point of view. Unless everything's in key C!

Comment: Try linguee.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer directly your question, but I would suggest teaching the theory the way you know it. If it's in English, do it in English.

Don't underestimate your student. After all, music theory, especially on high school level, is not that complicated. There are not so many words to learn. It's the concepts that might be difficult.

Maybe you can try to make sure to play or sing more examples, so that she can easier associate words with sounds. Maybe you can ask her some very basic questions during the classes to make sure she follows. This will be a better use of the time, than trying to translate to a system that you don't know and risking that you're teaching something completely wrong.

I'd suggest asking questions about teaching tips on Academia SE site. Many professors have experience in teaching foreign students, who often come with poor knowledge of the language.

Yes, it might be a bit confusing at the beginning, she may take a while to catch up. Certainly be gentle when grading! But in the end this will benefit her. All theory systems I know, all notation systems, have different flaws. Knowing several of them will only give her better understanding of music. Moreover, it will grant her access to more resources in the future.